# How does the blob: protocol work as <video> source?

Tags: html, video

A friend of mine was trying to download a Twitter embedded video and found something like this in the HTML code:

```
<video preload="auto" data-id="content" data-type="content" src="blob:https%3A//twitter.com/7897de6d-6eed-4905-9ed2-00ea3d2c99d5" class="visible paused" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></video>
```

I'm as puzzled as he was when I tried to find out the *real* source of the video stream (either by inspecting the browser network console and hitting a proxy). As the video played, the bytes seem to come out of nowhere.

How does the browser understand the blob "protocol"?

Answer (score 2):

Blobs are a way of handling memory that belongs to the browser. This could be files, or data from a canvas, or data that is computed in some other way. When data is loaded in such a way that `JavaScript` has a `blob` access to it, you can create a `BlobURI`, which is a url pointing to the internal memory structure.

In the case of twitter using `blob` url's for video, I would suspect that they are either proxying the video through a `canvas` in order to apply a filter, or are using `blobs` for some sort of local buffer. Either way, this means that the memory was accessible to JS at some point in the past.